# GetUserNameExA function cannot give user Details at system startup time(GINA)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dns, active-directory

i am using c++ win32 API.

i tried to get user details using GetUserNameExA();

i have use this function into system logondialog source(GINA).
in my logfile,it gives

`CN=ComputerName,CN=Computers,DC=JEGAN,DC=COM"`.

But it's used after logon on to system,at that time it gives user details like `"CN=sanju,CN=USERS,DC=JEGAN,DC=COM"` in my other solution.

i want user details only,but it gives system details at the logon time,how can i achieve user details at logontime?

**note:** i have already tried **ADSI,LDAP** functions & **directoryservices** cant able to use.so suggest any other system functions.

Comment: I don't understand. What does "But i have use this function into system logontime" mean?

Comment: @ David : using this function in system logondialog(clt+alt+dlt) source,it gives system details.but,after login and this function used in other solutions,it gives user details...how can i get user details in logon time.Got my point?

Comment: Nope. How do you go about adding code to the system logon dialog? GINA?

Comment: Add that to the question to make it clear. I take it you know that GINA does not exist in Vista, Win7, Win8 etc. It dies with XP.

Comment: @ David : i am using xp only.did u know about any answers for my Query?

Comment: Well, it's still not totally clear. I'm waiting for your to edit and improve your question.

Comment: The GINA code presumably doesn't run in the context of the user that is being logged on. It cannot because it's purpose is to perform the log on for that user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David is correct - the GINA DLL is loaded by the WinLogon.exe process.  Check Task Manager and you'll see that WinLogon.exe runs as Local System.  The `GetUserName` and `GetUserNameEx` functions provide information about the *identity for the current thread*:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435.aspx

From a 20,000 foot view, after a user's credentials have been validated, the GINA notifies all Network Providers of the successful login.  After this, it loads the user's profile and creates the user's shell (Explorer.exe) which is then displayed.

You might try using a Network Provider instead.  They are fully supported up through Windows 8 and multiple NPs can be defined for the system so you won't run into the 'chaining' issues that GINAs have.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378775.aspx

The `NPLogonNotify` function will receive the user's cleartext name, domain and password (sometimes you'll receive a UPN as username in which case the domain is blank).  You can use this information as is, perform LDAP-based lookups to AD or use `LogonUser` & `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` before calling `GetUserNameEx`.  Be extremely careful with this last approach since network providers run as Local system within the WinLogon.exe process.  **Always** call `RevertToSelf` and `CloseHandle` to undo/clean up the previous calls.

Comment: +1.  But if you *have* to use a GINA rather than a network provider, note that the GINA already knows the username, because ... well ... because that's it's job.  It's the GINA that *tells* the operating system what username and password to log on with in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The only (quite quirky) workaround for what you are trying to do is to log on some other user account on the side which has access to the domain and can thus query user details (don't remember the permissions needed in detail, though). Otherwise I'd suggest you go with Gregg's answer.

With a thread [impersonated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376391.aspx) as such user you should then be able to query the information for the user that you are going to log on (how do you even know by that time?) via [`NetUserGetInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb706729.aspx) and friends. Choose the `USER_INFO_*` `struct` that best suits your needs and simply ask the domain server for the information. This should also work on earlier and later systems (the functionality, not the GINA itself).